# How to verify a contract in etherscan older than 0.4.11?

Tags: etherscan, solc, contract-verification

It seems that the verification feature of Etherscan supports contracts written since Solidity 0.4.11.

I want to verify a contract written with Solidity 0.4.8. Is this possible?

I'm wondering if this is a new restriction, because I'm seeing other 0.4.8 contracts that are already verified.

Comment: The version 0.4.8 was released on January 2017, it is just too old and it has some bugs like "SkipEmptyStringLiteral". I'd suggesto to try a recent version of the compiler. If you can't upgrade it is best to contact Etherscan support directly.

Comment: @Ismael but you know, the problem is when a contract was deployed in 2015/2016 and users trusts more than 20,000 ᴇᴛʜ on it that you can’t redeploy using modern solidity for the sole sake of being able to verify it’s source code Etherscan !

Comment: @user2284570 In general using and old compiler with known bugs is a bad idea. Of course if you have deployed it successfully for several years and thousands of users, audited it at bytecode level and didn't found any bug you should be OK. Etherscan is a closed source block explorer that belong to a private company. You should contact them directly. From my experience they sometimes make exceptions for popular projects.